# Enable Delete button when row is more than one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Enable "Delete" button in forth col of the table when the row is more than one and Disable when the row is one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  $("#addrow2").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger" value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#myTable2").append(newRow);
    counter++;
  });
  $("#myTable2").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable2" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Full Address</th>
      <th>Business or Occupation</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="Del ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger" id="DeleteRow1" value="Delete" disabled='disabled'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `Enable Delete button in forth col of the table when the row is more than one and Disable when the row is one` if you repeat this 2 times it doesn't make it more clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prop()` to enabled/disabled .. also you can add/removeClass to prevent the click ..and on delete button click you need to check for the `length` of rows .. see the next code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  $("#addrow2").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger" value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#myTable2").append(newRow);
    $(".ibtnDel").prop('disabled' , false).removeClass('disabled'); // <<<<<< here
    counter++;
  });
  $("#myTable2").on("click", ".ibtnDel:not(.disabled)", function(event) { // <<<< here ..add :not(.disabled) to prevent the click for .disabled class element
  
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1;
   // >>>>>> here ..check for the row length
   if($("#myTable2 tbody tr").length === 1){
    $(".ibtnDel").prop('disabled' , true).addClass('disabled');
   }
   console.log($("#myTable2 tbody tr").length);
  });
});
```

```css
.disabled{
  background : red;
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addrow2">Add Row</button>
<table id="myTable2" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Full Address</th>
      <th>Business or Occupation</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="Del ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger" id="DeleteRow1" value="Delete" disabled='disabled'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```